# pro tools split left and right tracks

Tags: track

Hey guys, have just started using pro tools and am adjusting, when I import my omf it has split all my tracks into left and right tracks, is there any way to make the left and right track one single track with both left and right?

Answer (score 3):

Make a new stereo track, make sure the 2 mono signals are directly above one another (i.e. no track is in between them with other regions) and select both mono signals which should be on a stereo track with the selection tool and use your grabber tool in slip mode to drop them down onto the new stereo track. Remember to hold the control key so when you move the regions they do not move forward or backward inadvertently.

Then double check (it should be OK) but double check that the panning information is hard left and right like it should be (unless you want something else). Sometimes, not always, my panning information gets corrupted in the importation process so I have to reset the pan knobs for the regions/tracks I move.

Comment: @Gaelan You're welcome. And welcome to Social Sound Design. Let me know if you have any further questions and if this worked out OK.